# generating results using dropdown selections with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, variables

This may come out very convoluted but I will try to keep it as clear as possible.
I am trying to to find out if its possible to have an simple html form. That has 3 drop-downs that have similar options for different variable, that I want to be able to then use in JavaScript functions to return a sum. Ultimately I am trying to keep this all local without having to submit the info to a server to return the answer but if that is the way I have to go I will try to figure it out.

Example:  I have 3 drop-downs in a form. They are numberOfDice, sidesPerDice, and constMod;  all three drop downs are loaded with numbers (no text strings) numberOfDice values= 1-10, sidesPerDice values = 4sides, 6sides, 8sides, upto 20sides, and constmod values are plus0, plus1, plus2 etc upto plus10, I believe that each individual option in the drop-down has to have its own unique value (correct me if I'm wrong)

the below is the HTML for the form/user interface. I don't have any JavaScript as of yet as I was not sure if this would even work with JavaScript or if I would have to use asp.net or php. (Currently not working on server side scripting, but hopefully soon).

Any insight into this would be much appreciated. Also if you can make any recommendations to the form/drop-down code is correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <script src="Script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="totalHitPoints">
    <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-blue">
    <h1>Monster Stat Generater</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-container">
    <p>Number of Dice:</p>
    <select id="numberOfDice">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container">
    <p>Number of Sides per Dice</p>
    <select id="sidesPerDice">
    <option value="4sides">4</option>
    <option value="6sides">6</option>
    <option value="8sides">8</option>
    <option value="10sides">10</option>
    <option value="12sides">12</option>
    <option value="20sides">20</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container">
    <p>Constitution Modifier</p>
    <select id="constMod">
    <option value="plus0">0</option>
    <option value="plus1">1</option>
    <option value="plus2">2</option>
    <option value="plus3">3</option>
    <option value="plus4">4</option>
    <option value="plus5">5</option>
    <option value="plus6">6</option>
    <option value="plus7">7</option>
    <option value="plus8">8</option>
    <option value="plus9">9</option>
    <option value="plus10">10</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    </form>
    <button id="form_submit" type="submit">Get Hit Points</button>

    <div class="w3-container" style="width:128px;">
        <p>Total Hit Points:</p>
        <p id="getHitPoints"class="w3-border w3-center w3-padding" style="width: 64px;">0</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I don't think that i was clear enough in my original description.  I think that all of the solutions (which are great and provided me with information that will come in handy in the near future) are totaling the sum's of the values in the drop downs. Which reading back is what it sounds like I was attempting. However there is more that I am looking to do.

What I want to happen is the user (ME) Will select the variables with the drop downs.  i.e.  4 die rolls of 8 sided dice with a + 4 modifier. All of the solutions appear to be taking the values (4, 8, 4) and adding them for a total of 16 when I am trying to get the total of 4 eight sided dice + 4. which should return a value between 8 (1,1,1,1,4) and 36 (8,8,8,8,4). I hope that clears it up.

This might help as well,  Currently this is part of another script.

```
function getRandom() {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
```

for this function I would want the drop down for sidePerDie to change the multiplier to the value of the drop down. Either 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 or 20.

and also the following

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
roll = getRandom();
diceTotal += roll;
d.push(roll);
}
```

This rolls the dice 4 times. I would like the drop down to change the 4 to the number of rolls that i would like.

That way when I click the Get hit points button. the function will fire and roll the type of die (4, 6, 8, etc side) a number of times (1-10) and then add the modifier to the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
      var submit_button = document.getElementById("form_submit");
submit_button.addEventListener("click", getSum);

 function getSum() {

var constMod = parseInt(document.getElementById("constMod").value),
    sidesPerDice = parseInt(document.getElementById("sidesPerDice").value),
    numberOfDice = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberOfDice").value);

    var total=0;
    var div_to_fill = document.getElementById("getHitPoints");

    var randomVariableArray = getRandom(numberOfDice, sidesPerDice, constMod);
 console.log(randomVariableArray);
        for(var i in randomVariableArray) { 
        total += randomVariableArray[i]; 
    }
    div_to_fill.innerHTML = total;console.log(total);
}

function getRandom(numberOfDice, sidesPerDice, constMod) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfDice; ++i) {
    rollDie = Math.floor(Math.random() * sidesPerDice) + 1;
    arr.push(rollDie);
  }
  arr.push(constMod);
  return arr;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  
    <form id="totalHitPoints">
    <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-blue">
    <h1>Monster Stat Generater</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-container">
    <p>Number of Dice:</p>
    <select id="numberOfDice">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container">
    <p>Number of Sides per Dice</p>
    <select id="sidesPerDice">
    <option value="4">4 sides</option>
    <option value="6">6 sides</option>
    <option value="8">8 sides</option>
    <option value="10">10 sides</option>
    <option value="12">12 sides</option>
    <option value="20">20 sides</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container">
    <p>Constitution Modifier</p>
    <select id="constMod">
    <option value="0">0plus</option>
    <option value="1">1plus</option>
    <option value="2">2plus</option>
    <option value="3">3plus</option>
    <option value="4">4plus</option>
    <option value="5">5plus</option>
    <option value="6">6plus</option>
    <option value="7">7plus</option>
    <option value="8">8plus</option>
    <option value="9">9plus</option>
    <option value="10">10plus</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    </form>
    <button id="form_submit" type="submit">Get Hit Points</button>

    <div class="w3-container" style="width:128px;">
        <p>Total Hit Points:</p>
        <p id="getHitPoints"class="w3-border w3-center w3-padding" style="width: 64px;">0</p>
    </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

**EXPLANATION:** first of all your option values should be integers and unqiue.. make your html as follows:

```
<form id="totalHitPoints">
    <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-blue">
    <h1>Monster Stat Generater</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-container">
    <p>Number of Dice:</p>
    <select id="numberOfDice">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container">
    <p>Number of Sides per Dice</p>
    <select id="sidesPerDice">
    <option value="4">4 sides</option>
    <option value="6">6 sides</option>
    <option value="8">8 sides</option>
    <option value="10">10 sides</option>
    <option value="12">12 sides</option>
    <option value="20">20 sides</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container">
    <p>Constitution Modifier</p>
    <select id="constMod">
    <option value="0">0plus</option>
    <option value="1">1plus</option>
    <option value="2">2plus</option>
    <option value="3">3plus</option>
    <option value="4">4plus</option>
    <option value="5">5plus</option>
    <option value="6">6plus</option>
    <option value="7">7plus</option>
    <option value="8">8plus</option>
    <option value="9">9plus</option>
    <option value="10">10plus</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    </form>
    <button id="form_submit" type="submit">Get Hit Points</button>

    <div class="w3-container" style="width:128px;">
        <p>Total Hit Points:</p>
        <p id="getHitPoints"class="w3-border w3-center w3-padding" style="width: 64px;">0</p>
    </div>
```

next your javascript function add a event listener click:

```
var submit_button = document.getElementById("form_submit");
submit_button.addEventListener("click", getSum);
```

then define the actual function which calculates sum.
Then first parse the options to int:

```
function getSum() {

var constMod = parseInt(document.getElementById("constMod").value),
    sidesPerDice = parseInt(document.getElementById("sidesPerDice").value),
    numberOfDice = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberOfDice").value);
```

Then dine another function `getRandom` which gets the number of random dies as array

```
var randomVariableArray = getRandom(numberOfDice, sidesPerDice, constMod);

function getRandom(numberOfDice, sidesPerDice, constMod) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfDice; ++i) {
    rollDie = Math.floor(Math.random() * sidesPerDice) + 1;
    arr.push(rollDie);
  }
  arr.push(constMod);
  return arr;
}
```

Then loop through the array and add all the values

```
for(var i in randomVariableArray) { 
            total += randomVariableArray[i]; 
        }
```

the fill the div with the sum using `innerHtml`

```
var div_to_fill = document.getElementById("getHitPoints");
div_to_fill.innerHTML = total;console.log(total);

}
```

on whole you js will be

```
    var submit_button = document.getElementById("form_submit");
submit_button.addEventListener("click", getSum);

 function getSum() {

var constMod = parseInt(document.getElementById("constMod").value),
    sidesPerDice = parseInt(document.getElementById("sidesPerDice").value),
    numberOfDice = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberOfDice").value);

    var total=0;
    var div_to_fill = document.getElementById("getHitPoints");

    var randomVariableArray = getRandom(numberOfDice, sidesPerDice, constMod);
 console.log(randomVariableArray);
        for(var i in randomVariableArray) { 
        total += randomVariableArray[i]; 
    }
    div_to_fill.innerHTML = total;console.log(total);
}

function getRandom(numberOfDice, sidesPerDice, constMod) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfDice; ++i) {
    rollDie = Math.floor(Math.random() * sidesPerDice) + 1;
    arr.push(rollDie);
  }
  arr.push(constMod);
  return arr;
}
```

Link to fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/qfxvydmp/][1]

Comment: Thank you for the response and the info. I updated the OP with further detail as I dont think that I was clear in what I was looking to do.

Comment: check the modified and hope it helps!

Comment: So I was able to update my script.js file and html however when I click the button i do not get any result in the getHitPoints div field.

Comment: ok so its working in fiddle however when i load the code into notepad (old school) add the script file to the <head> element it will not fire. I have tried in multiple browsers and copy and pasted directly from fiddle. I will continue to work on the linking and make sure the the html to JavaScript file is linked appropriately. thank you again.

Comment: I have gone over this code multiple times now and everything is 100% yet it still wont fire in Chrome or IE. Any Ideas.

Comment: as a last ditch effort I even put the javascript in the html doc inside <script> tags.  As this is really only going to be used by me its not a big deal to have it in the source, however it still will not fire in the browser.  There has to be something that I am missing but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

Comment: as a final resort to help you I've added the `full code` block in the answer. Copy that into any text editor save it and run in any browser

Comment: Thank you for all the help. It finally worked in browser. Totally my fault. Fat fingered something that was preventing the script from firing. Again Thanks. This works perfectly and will make my life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed possible. This post on eduMaven does a good job of showing how to do pretty much this exact thing: http://edumaven.com/javascript-programming/get-value-of-selected-option . This post gives an example in pure JS:

```
var selector = document.getElementById('id_of_select');
var value = selector[selector.selectedIndex].value;
```

This is easy enough to do is pure JS, but another search for the same problem in jQuery pulls up this example: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/ . This post shows that the jQuery way is just:

```
var value = $( "#myselect" ).val();
```

It is a little bit unclear exactly what you want to do with this information. I am assuming based on what you did say that you want to do something with the selected values when the user clicks "submit", without actually sending an HTTP request.

To do this part, I would actually skip the "submit" type of the button, and instead define an "onclick" event for the button, as shown here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp . The example given is:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Then, you will need to define a function in your JS file to actually perform whatever computation you want to do. This could really be any calculation you want--this is just a matter of manipulating javascript variables. From what you say you want above, it would look something like:

```
function myFunction(){

    // get the integer values from your select options
    var numDice = parseInt( $( "#numberOfDice" ).val() );
    var sidesDice = parseInt( $( "#sidesPerDice" ).val() );
    var mod = parseInt( $( "#constMod" ).val() );

    // "roll" numDice times
    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numDice; i++) { 
        // roll a random number and add mod, then add to sum
        sum += Math.floor((Math.random() * sidesDice) + 1) + mod;
    }

    // output answer in whatever form you see fit -- 
    // could be put back into the html (as shown in the links provided), printed to console, or used in a later calculation
    console.log(sum);
}
```

I hope this walkthrough will help point you and others in the right direction with some of this stuff. However, you should really look into some of the basics of using jQuery of JS to select html elements--this really is pretty much the basic use case of these technologies! It would be helpful for you to get more familiar with the basics before trying to fell your way blindly here. There are plenty of resources online, including the ones I linked to (which were found by a quick search; that said, knowing the proper search terms can, admittedly, be tricky).

Comment: Thank you for the response and the info. I updated the OP with further detail as I dont think that I was clear in what I was looking to do.

Comment: What would you like to do with the total? This solution just logs it to the console for some internal use, check all the other answers for how to replace the text of your button with the total. Also, I am still unsure how the modifier is supposed to work (does it impact the value of each die cast?). Still, I hope all these answers gave you enough to extrapolate from.

Comment: The Modifier is a bonus to the total of the die roll. So depending on some other outside factors the modifier can be anywhere from 0 to 10. I have another page to determine a characters starting stats. It rolls 4 six sided dice removes the lowest number and adds the remaining 3 for 6 different stats.  This is all done with 1 click and nothing server side.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - remove the value attribute from each option element as this will make things easier when obtaining the values from the select elements

```
<div class="w3-container">
<select id="numberOfDice">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
....
</select>
</div>

<div class="w3-container">
<p>Number of Sides per Dice</p>
<select id="sidesPerDice">
<option>4</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>8</option>
...
</select>
</div>

<div class="w3-container">
<p>Constitution Modifier</p>
<select id="constMod">
<option>0</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
...
</select>
</div>
```

You can remove the form element also.
You need to add a JavaSCript event to the button so it knows what to do once you click on the button.

```
<button id="form_submit" onclick='doCalc()'>Get Hit Points</button>
```

You need a JavaScript function

```
function doCalc() {
  //--- get the input values
  var parseInt(numberOfDice = document.getElementById('numberOfDice').value,10);
...
  //-- do you calculations
...
  //--- display your results
  document.getElementById('getHitPoints').innerHTML = myResults;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and the info. I updated the OP with further detail as I dont think that I was clear in what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

The values for your select dropdowns don't have to be unique, they can be anything you like. You've given each of your selects a unique id e.g `id="numberOfDice"` which is good - the `<option>` tag in each of them is a child of the `<select>` tag, and we can get that value using javascript.

I'd remove the text from your values so you're just dealing with numbers - e.g `value="plus0"` should become `value="0"` for everything.

Include the jquery library in your head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then in your Script.js add the following

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

// listen for a click event on your button 
$('#form_submit').click(function(event) { 

// stop the form submitting data - we just want to update your html

event.preventDefault();

// get the values of your selects as variables

var numberOfDice = $('#numberOfDice').val();
var sidesPerDice = $('#sidesPerDice').val();
var constMod = $('#constMod').val();

// do the calculation
var sum = numberOfDice + sidesPerDice + constMod;

// now update your html with your calculation

$('p#getHitPoints').html(sum);

});


});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and the info. I updated the OP with further detail as I dont think that I was clear in what I was looking to do.